# Get record count from sql and pass it to xml using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have below query which search the data from  mysql table and exports to XML using php, But I can't figure out how to pass the records count to MatchCount element in xml.

Below is my script :

```
 <?php
header ("content-type: text/xml");
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'admin', 'Customer_1') or die("cannot connect");

$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

$RegistrationMark = $_GET['RegistrationMark'];
$MachineName  = $_GET['MachineName'];



$qr= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `EarlsdonMSIN_anpr_vega` where `RegistrationMark` like '%" .$RegistrationMark. "%'");

$xml.='<CaptureResponse  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\CaptureResponse.xsd"> <MachineName>'.$_GET['MachineName'].'</MachineName><MatchCount>10</MatchCount><ResponseDateTime>2017-12-20T14:00:00</ResponseDateTime><MatchRecords ImageURI = "http://192.192.192.200/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Lanein1/EarlsdonMSIN/">';

while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($qr))
{
 $xml.='<MatchLine><VehicleRegistration>'.$res['RegistrationMark'].'</VehicleRegistration><LastStatus>IN</LastStatus><datetime>'.$res['datetime'].T.$res['time'].'</datetime><ImageFile>'.$res['image_name'].'</ImageFile></MatchLine>';
}

$xml.='</MatchRecords></CaptureResponse>';
echo $xml;
?>
```

Comment: where do you execute the query,do you know what string concatenation is, do you know what sql can do?

Comment: Please see my edited query

Comment: Do you want to show rows count ?

Comment: yes please Mr Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the count

```
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($qr);
```

then you need to concatenate the result

```
$xml.='<CaptureResponse  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\CaptureResponse.xsd"> <MachineName>'.$_GET['MachineName'].'</MachineName><MatchCount>'.$row_cnt.'</MatchCount><ResponseDateTime>2017-12-20T14:00:00</ResponseDateTime><MatchRecords ImageURI = "http://192.192.192.200/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Lanein1/EarlsdonMSIN/">';
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to get current time on resposedatetime on xml..please

Comment: yeah got it Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Php provide`mysqli_num_rows()` for counting the rows according to the query, so you can use it after your `mysqli_query()`

Try this,

```
 $MatchCount=mysqli_num_rows($qr);
```

Then replace and concatenate `$MatchCount` with `10`. Following is an example

```
$xml.='<CaptureResponse  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\CaptureResponse.xsd"> <MachineName>'.$_GET['MachineName'].'</MachineName><MatchCount>'.$MatchCount.'</MatchCount><ResponseDateTime>2017-12-20T14:00:00</ResponseDateTime><MatchRecords ImageURI = "http://192.192.192.200/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Lanein1/EarlsdonMSIN/">';
```